# Movie about a woman trapped in a room trying to put together clues with a countdown clock

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I only remember a few things about this movie and I’m hoping someone recognizes it.

There was a woman trapped in a room and she had to try to figure out clues while on a countdown.  She came across some things in the room and there was someone “trapped” in a room next to her.

At the end she finds out that she was out there to trigger her memories because something happened at a lab she worked at and it made her lose her memory and they needed her to remember something to save someone I think.

The woman that was in the room next to her turned out to be her friend or coworker or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were there any science fiction aspects to this story?  From what you have here it sounds like a relatively mundane thriller.

Comment: Almost sounds like an episode of _Murdoch Mysteries_ from about 6 years ago except for the "lab she worked at" part. Murdoch and Dr. Ogden were taken captive in neighboring rooms and had to figure out how to escape. No SFF aspects there...

Comment: It may be one of the scenes from The Cube movie https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/

Comment: This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in [the Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Valorum Looks like a "junk science" story, so probably on-topic.

Comment: @Spencer - 'Woman with amnesia is tortured' could just as easily be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[*Riddle Room*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2180317/) 2016

> Emily Burns is being held captive in a room with no idea how she got there. Determined to escape and return to her family, Emily discovers clues within the room that help explain why she's there...but will they help her escape?

I've been looking myself and just found it while browsing through 'memory loss' movies. It's a pretty good movie to watch.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a pretty sparse answer; you just give a title.  You could make this a better answer by including a summary of the movie, noting especially how it matches the question, and possibly a link to the trailer or IMDb.

Comment: (Note that *Riddle Room* does not appear to be on-topic for this site.)

Comment: @DavidW - If it turns out to be the right answer, we'll close the question off.